# Inserir rows no topo da tabela

Tags: php, tabela-html

Estou com o seguinte problema, criei um formulário em que o valor que o usuário escrever tem de ir ao topo da tabela, deixando os mais antigos para baixo, ou fazer com que o meu SELECT consiga selecionar só os 10 últimos registros da tabela.Alguém pode me ajudar?

ATUALIZAÇÃO!!!

O meu código está assim :

```
$result = "SELECT id, filmes FROM dados_rec ORDER by filmes DESC LIMIT 10";
$query = mysqli_query($link, $result);

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[1];
echo $row[2];
echo $row[3];
```

Ele imprime só o primeiro, que no caso é o nome de um filme, mas ele ignora os outros "echos"

Comment: Acho que é mais simples fazer um select com `ORDER BY campo DESC`

Comment: Eu já fiz isso, mas ele me mostra em ordem alfabética, eu preciso só que ele me mostre os últimos registros

Comment: Se vc tiver um campo com o registro (data e hora) do negocio manda ordernar por ele ou pode fazer pelo id.

Comment: Você pode me explicar como fazer pelo id? Comecei agora no php e não sei quase nada.

Comment: No lugar de colocar o campo com a título/nome no `ODER BY` coloca o campo o id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pegar os 10 últimos:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Para exibir todas as linhas:

```
$sql = "SELECT id,nome FROM `table` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die (mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
    echo $row['id']." - ."row['nome'];
}
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado, mas quando peço pra printar as linhas da tabela ele só printa a primeira linha.Estou utilizando "echo $row[1];" a primeira linhs printa certinho, mas as outras não, tem como me ajudar?

Comment: @Luvinicius como está imprimindo? coloque na pergunta, pra que eu possa te ajudar.

Comment: Editei, veja se consegue me ajudar, parece um erro simples, mas não consigo consertar de jeito nenhum.

Answer (score 0):

Não precisa fazer isso, basta selecionar os últimos registros da tabela usando

```
SELECT * FROM dados_rec ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Eu já fiz isso, mas ele me mostra em ordem alfabética, eu preciso só que ele me mostre os últimos registros.

Comment: você deve estar selecionando o registro filmes, vou editar a resposta e veja se funciona